# How to Restrict hasMany with limited numbers in domain class in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many

I am developing a grails application, I have domain classes like Tip, TipTag. Concept is, For a Tip I should have only 5 TipTag.

```
class Tip {
    String description
    static hasMany = [tags:TipTag]

    static constraints = {
        description(nullable:false,size:50..500)
    }   
}
```

How to restrict this in grails??
Any other way of doing this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [maxSize](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/maxSize.html) [constraint](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) should do the job for you:

```
class Tip {
    String description
    static hasMany = [tags:TipTag]

    static constraints = {
        description(nullable:false,size:50..500)
        tags(maxSize: 5)
    }   
}
```